# Convert Sql Query into Mongodb Query

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I have one SQL query written below :

```
Select * from student where fname + ' ' + lname like '%abc mno%';
```

How to write the same query in MongoDB?

Comment: check this mongo sql mapping 
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/

Comment: This is an odd question, as presumably, your data in Mongo would be structured differently than in a relational database.

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collection.find({"name":/.*abc mno.*/})
```

OR

```
db.collection.find({"name":/abc mno/})
```

You can also use [mongo regex](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)

```
db.collection.find({"name":{'$regex': 'abc mno'}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below examples,

```
db.student.find({name:{$regex:"a"}})  //Contain a anywhere
```

or

```
db.student.find({name:{$regex:"e$"}}) //Ends with e
```

or

```
db.student.find({name:{$regex:"^A"}}) //Start with A
```